# How can I implement a input TextField with expression icons supported on iPhone application?

Tags: iphone

How can I implement a input TextField with expression icons or some highlighted string supported on iPhone application? Is there any open source library can be refered?

Answer (score 0):

```
  Try something like this.

           self.myTextField.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber

            UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber

            UIDataDetectorTypeLink

            UIDataDetectorTypeAddress

            UIDataDetectorTypeCalendarEvent

            UIDataDetectorTypeNone

            UIDataDetectorTypeAll
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I want to implement the input and display for some custom icons such as ":)", ":(", "@name", etc. Can I finish this work by UITextField?

Comment: you try this link for adding the similies http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_styled_text_label.php